# What are Intel execution modes?

Tags: intel, execution, internals

I'm trying to study a bit about x86 internals, I read about System Management Mode, Real Mode , Protected Mode and Long Mode, however I heard there are a few more undocumented
can anyone refer me to any such documentation which proves that or explains them ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about only operating modes or about x86 modes in general? [The wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) on this documents all these modes. Your question is a bit broad.